# PTIJ: Are there any Judaic on-line stores that sell Yiddishe cups?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

I've checked Eichler's and even looked on EBay but I haven't found a real Yiddishe drinking cup, preferably one strong enough for piping hot coffee.

Does anyone know any on-line site that sells them?

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 7):

Here is one for sale online. You should try the Google machine next time.

http://www.cafepress.com/mf/20523775/a-yiddish-cup_mugs?utm_medium=cpc&utm_term=147439283&utm_source=google&utm_campaign=sem-cpc-product-ads&utm_content=search-pla&productId=147439283

Comment: I love how this actually is the answer to the OPs question yet you have only one upvote *my upvote

Comment: I hope my comment was responsible for the upvotes!

Comment: @shoel yes it was at least parsha lee

Answer (score 4):

Try on top of your neck. That would seem to be a Yiddishe Kup that can drink piping hot coffee.

Answer (score 3):

You may have overlooked the following seforim that are without  question yiddishe kups:

- Tosfos HaRosh - gauranteed to add much yiddishe brain power
- Chidushei haRosh - a new yiddishe cup
- Teshuvos haRosh - recycled yiddishe cup

Comment: You forgot the sefer Besamim Rosh

Comment: @NafkaMina but that is not an authentic yiddishe kup... it's a forgery ;-)

Comment: +1 i was waiting for someone to point that out! i will counter that at least according to the Chid"a it wasnt a forgery!

Answer (score 2):

Of course you wont find on ebay they only sell goyishe cups.
I suggest you look at [www.yad2.co.il](http://www.Yad2.co.il) they only sell yidishe cups
or [www.janglo.net](http://www.janglo.net)

Comment: Are those two actual sites?

Comment: Yes. Based in israel